# How to create a button with an image and text WatchKit

Tags: watchkit

I want to create a tappable button with an icon and some text.. kind of like how the map app does it. See the attached picture below.

I've currently tried having a button that is set to the `Group` mode for content. However, this makes the background clear and I wasn't sure if there were any better options. Another option that came to my mind was creating a table view with one cell that took up half the width but that would be very hacky as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just create two groups. Then you can change the background color, add an image and text label. To make it clickable simply add a tapGestureRecognizer to the group and it will function just like a button.